# What style is used in gmail app for the indeterminate progressbar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-progressbar

I am trying to find some hint as to what style is used for the indeterminate progressbar in gmail app for android. The one that's at the bottom right corner of the app. I've managed to change the item in action bar with setActionView... Now I can't find the exact style they used. Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Regards,
Parvaz Bhaskar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style you're looking for is `?android:attr/progressBarStyle`.

Surprisingly, other than `?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge`, it has a white background which is not indicated with the name difference.